# delete row when delete buttton is pressed from table in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Everything is working fine.

The problem is when I press the delete button, it deletes but not immediately from table. It deletes when I reload the page. I **replace** the student array in localStorage when I press delete. Your help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
const history = useHistory();
let student = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('student'))
```

This is the function for the deletion of an item

```js
const deleteStudent = (event)=>{
  let id = event.currentTarget.id
  let students = student.map(student=>Number(student.id))
  let index = students.indexOf(Number(id))
  student.splice(index,1)
  localStorage.setItem('student',JSON.stringify(student))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useEffect()` hook for re rendering the component. You can set the dependency when it should render. I am not sure about the use case for local storage here but you can use `useState()` hook to update the data and render the component or you can use the `useEffect()` hook by adding the dependencies and render the component.

Link for the useEffect hook - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Link for the useState hook - [https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

```js
  //declare this in the start of the component
  const studentsData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('student'))
  const [students, setStudents] = useState(studentsData);

  const deleteStudent = (event)=>{
     let id = event.currentTarget.id
     let studentIds = students.map(student=>Number(student.id))
     let index = studentIds.indexOf(Number(id))
     students.splice(index,1)
     localStorage.setItem('student',JSON.stringify(student))
  }

  useEffect(() => {
     setStudents(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('student')))
  }, [localStorage.getItem('student')]);
```

Comment: how do I implement it? can you kindly write the code for that program? or do I have to just put this?

Comment: Edited my code. This way you can handle. If you dont need to store in the local storage you can use useState hook for that.